# What app uses this notification icon?

Tags: notification-icons

[image: Notification bar icon]

It looks like a partial alphabet *a* in black color over a white circular background.

Comment: If this is an application icon, rather than a system-driven one, it will appear on the left side of the notification bar. Pull down the notification menu and the notification can be long-pressed to bring up the AppInfo button. Press the AppInfo button to take you to the page for the relevant app.

Comment: it's most def an [app notification icon](http://i.imgur.com/8sfJ3DK.png) I just stumbled upon in the Internet and I'm curious what it stands for

Answer (score 1):

That is a notification icon from [Podcast Addict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bambuna.podcastaddict&hl=en). See [this screenshot](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wzpT9bPiUCsmt8I9zvJ9YwuIwjo21Mc7RWU6PIjMglWotWVTZye1o_x_6JyatHQq-IY=h900) for an example.

It's not the icon you see when content is playing or paused: I think it's the icon you see when the app wants to tell you there is new content available.